# colspan/rowspan not appearing as expected in HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

I have attached this photo to show you what the question is asking with correct formatting.

[image]

[Click here to see my output with the code used below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjq26.png)

```html
<h1>7.
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</h1>
```

I used the rowspan and colspan as instructed, and yet my table is still missing the larger spaces as the example shows is needed, so I am looking for guidance on what I am missing. The numbers are aligned correctly, just missing the spaces. I know the code should seem fine, but the program checker is saying it's wrong.

Comment: I have no idea why my previous comment was deleted but again, I don't understand what the issue is. Your code seems fine. Please elaborate. Also, what program checker are you referring to? Finally, you didn't properly close your `<h1>` element.

Comment: It is a program called zyBooks. The error message says this: "Answer for question is empty.
Your value
false
Expected value
true
Test aborted." Also, clearly my spacing is off somehow as it does not look like the example.

Comment: also, had the closing h1 tag, just forgot to include in my original post.

Answer (score -1):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table.td {
      bold: normal;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <h1>7</h1>
    <table style="text-align:center;">
    <tr >
        <th colspan="3"><h1>1</h1></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><h1>2</h1></td>
        <td><h1>3</h1></td>
        <td><h1>4</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1>5</h1></td>
        <td><h1>6</h1></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: or simply add <h1> tag to all td with values so that it replicates precisely the expected result.

Comment: An explanation instead of a code dump is usually more useful. Also, `bold: normal;` is invalid

Comment: Please provide some explanation of your changes in your answer. Don't expect readers to have to compare it to the original post line-by-line.

Comment: this does not equal the output I posted.